# How to Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, com-interop

I want to create a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application object using asp.net. However, when I write the following line, an exception is thrown.

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Error Message:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 800702e4 The requested operation requires elevation. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800702E4).

I have Windows 8 64 Bit platform and Microsoft Office 2007 32 Bit Version.
I don't want to remove Microsoft Office and re-install the 64 Bit Version.

I've already tried changing platform target to x86 (In Visual Studio / Project Properties / Build) and done lots of google search.

How can I use the `Application` object without installing microsoft office (64 bit).

Thanks.

Comment: If you run the program once as administrator does it work as a non administrator if you run it again?

Comment: AFAIK, you need the group "Distributed COM-User" (not sure whether it's called exactly that way in english Windows)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It works as administrator.
Atmocreations I've already given necessary permissions to excel application (from the Component Services)

Comment: Have you tried sysinternals process monitor to look for Access Denied errors?